# The security to the party (Spaghetti's back!)

Tags: mathematics, password

In celebration of catching the spaghetti thieves, a new party is being thrown!

But the thieves have relatives who think they can do better! I wonder if they can.

So they're hiding outside listening, and they hear many guests coming, sadly, many were like them trying to get in, meaning they didn't get a lot of information:

A man and woman come along. Each is given a number. The man is given 5 and the woman is given 10. The man responds 10 and gets in. The woman said 5 and gets in.

Then two kids come along, given the numbers 3 and 9. They responded 6 and 4.5. Kid #1 gets in, but #2 is trampled on by an elephant.

Then a man comes along, he gets 5, he says he'll come back later.

What should the 2 thieves do when they go up to the door?

*Table summary:*

```
Man    5    10    Right
Woman  10   5     Right 
Kid    3    6     Right
Kid    9    4.5   Wrong
Man    5    ?     ?
```

Comment: This is a really easy one. Good thing downvotes are for bad questions, not easy ones ;D

Comment: Why bother stealing spaghetti when there's an elephant right there for you to steal?

Comment: @KSmarts I know right!

Comment: Or, you could scare the elephant into rampaging, and steal the spaghetti in the confusion. Hey, it's tagged "lateral-thinking". Does that mean that this is a valid answer?

Comment: @KSmarts lateral-thinking does **not** mean anything goes.

Comment: But lateral-thinking **does** usually mean identifying and rejecting unstated assumptions. You did not say that the thieves had to receive a number and respond correctly. Actually, you didn't say that anyone did. Can they just go in?

Comment: I'd appreciate if puzzles like this gave a summary table of inputs and outputs, to make them easier to pick out. But then there's one where the story matters for the rule, and them not doing so would give an unintentional hint. Hmm...

Comment: @KSmarts Changed lateral-thinking to math. Happy?

Comment: @warspyking No. I wanted to ride the elephant. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the number is odd, double it.  If it is even, halve it.